# Baofeng UV-82 pcb component identification

Tags: baofeng, ht

Baofeng UV-82 PCB smd component burned (marked in yellow) but cannot identify the component number or type.

Google search found this page with pcb image but its different version of pcb https://radioaficion.com/cms/uv-82-circuit-description/

[image]

Any websites with hi-res images of ham radio equipment's pcbs or schematics?

Comment: It's surely a capacitor. But what value (and voltage rating?) if you can't find schematics, then you need to experiment. Disconnect the last transistor (at the bottom) and measure through the circuit with a VNA, and try various values of capacitor. Voltage rating is also tricky, you get capacitors rated for hundreds of volts and several amps of RF current, that are no bigger than usual

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!